# changeorientation call onpageselected before oncreateview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with 3 fragments; in my main Activity I handle `onPageChangeListener`:

```
private class CustomPageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        fragments.get(position).onShowedFragment(context);
        super.onPageSelected(position);
    }
}
```

The call to `onShowedFragment(context)` loads data into fragment (I load data on demand). I am putting data loaded into a `ListView`:

```
@Override
public void onShowedFragment(Context context) {
    databaseService = DatabaseService.getInstance(context);
    mAdapter = new Capitulo100ListAdapter(context);
    databaseService.capitulo100ObjectSet.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    lst100.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    try {
        //load my data
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //...
    }
    super.onShowedFragment(context);
}
```

When I rotate the device, Android recreates the activity and calls `onPageSelected`, and that calls the method `onShowedFragment` on my fragment, but at the time the ListView called **lst100** is null (I initialize the views in the method onCreateView of the fragment), then the line `lst100.setAdapter(mAdapter)` causes an error.

I am not using `android:configChanges`

How can I upload my data when the ListView is created after the rotation of the device?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private class CustomPageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // call super.onPageSelected() before onShowedFragment()
        super.onPageSelected(position);
        fragments.get(position).onShowedFragment(context);
       
    }
}
```

//initialize views in onCreateView()

```
databaseService = DatabaseService.getInstance(context);
mAdapter = new Capitulo100ListAdapter(context);
databaseService.capitulo100ObjectSet.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

//if list is not null, setAdapter.

```
   @Override
public void onShowedFragment(Context context) {
    if(lst!=null)
    lst100.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    try {
        //load my data
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //...
    }
    super.onShowedFragment(context);
}
```

//if still it's not working use MVVM architecture component .it will handle all issues related to activity recreation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call some method whenever the fragment is shown to the user, please use `setUserVisibleHint` which is called from adapter whenever corresponding Fragment is shown.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are either not initializing lst100 after activity's recreation or initializing it wrong anyways try getting a reference to the ListView in onShowedFragment itself.

```
@Override
public void onShowedFragment(Context context) {
    ...
    
    ListView listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.your_listview_id);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    ...
    super.onShowedFragment(context);
}
```